# How can Set Tax field Required for different store view in magento

Tags: magento

In Magento **admin->customer configuration->Name and Address Options** 
there is option for setup tax field required or not. But if I switch store view to other store then Name and Address Options is not showing. I don't know why magento made this limitation, Is there any solution so that I can set tax field required for different store view.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Store views handle the way your store looks like, they don't handle business logic. To adept your store for different languages, users with mobile phones, etc use store view. For base currency, prices or taxes you have to use different websites. 

Maybe this link helps http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work